Finding $\lim_{x\to1}(x^2-1)^3\sin\left(\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^3\right)$ in terms of $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$
Ask me to find the following limit:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}
(x^2 - 1)^3 \sin\left(\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^3\right),
$$
in terms of the limit of:
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to 0}
\frac{\sin(x)}{x}.
$$
What I've done:
I rewrite the expression
$
(x^2 - 1)^3 \sin\left(\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^3\right)
$
as:
$
\left[\frac{1}{\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^3}\right] \cdot (x+1)^3 \cdot \sin\left(\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^3\right).
$
I make a change of variable:
$
u = \left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^3.$
If $ x \rightarrow 1$, $ u \rightarrow \infty$, and this is a problem because I want to make the $
\lim\limits_{x \to 0}
\frac{\sin(x)}{x}.
$ appears, any hint?

As $\sin$ is bounded, the limit should be $0$. It doesn't seem to me that the limit of $\sin x/x$ is needed here...

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 1}
(x^2 - 1)^3 \sin\left(\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^3\right)
$$
Solution: Let $t=\left(x-1\right)^3$, then $x-1={\sqrt[3]{t}}$. The limit terms out to be $$0=\lim_{t\to 0}-8t\leq\lim_{t\to 0 }8t\sin \frac{1}{t}\leq\lim_{x\to 0}8t=0\implies \lim_{t\to 0}8t\frac{1}{t}=0$$
There is no need for $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ to appear, since $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}\left(\frac{1}{x-1}\right)^3=\infty\neq 0$.

What about the squeeze theorem?
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x\to 1}(x^{2} - 1)^{3}\sin\left(\frac{1}{(x - 1)^{3}}\right) & = \lim_{x\to 1}(x + 1)^{3}(x - 1)^{3}\sin\left(\frac{1}{(x - 1)^{3}}\right) = 0
\end{align*}
that's because the $\sin$ function is bounded and $x - 1$ converges to $0$ as $x\to 1$.

I can't use it):
